# correct way to turn EAR module into OSGI bundle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi

There is a necessity to turn part of EAR (namely - war) into OSGI bundle and retain it's interoperability. Glassfish 3.0.1 already has `osgi-web-container` module and I succeeded to deploy standalone OSGI war.

But in case of of ex-enterprise war it looks a bit difficult to me.

1. What do I do with EJB calls from
   inside future OSGI war? Is it enough
   to replace `@EJB` injections with true JNDI
   lookups?
2. What about APIs and libraries
   shared across EAR? I could split and
   rearrange them, but still I will
   have at least one jar needed by both
   EAR and OSGI war. Duplicate, make it
   as OSGI-bundle itself and make it
   available to ear somehow, place it
   GF domain's library path?
3. Any other ideas, advices which could
   make that hybrid working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things to try out:

- No need to replace `@EJB` by JNDI lookup. Your `@EJB` will continue to work even inside your OSGi War (aka WAB).
- You can install the shared library as a bundle, then it will be visible to both OSGi war as well as legacy EAR/WAR.

I suggest you follow up in [GlassFish forum](http://www.java.net/forums/glassfish/glassfish).

Comment: Thanks alot! Will try. I believe you're the same Sahoo owning the http://www.java.net/blogs/ss141213/ ? If yes I'd vote up your answer ten times if I could :) And here is small question: is your reply applicable to GF 3.0.1 or it implies using 3.1 builds? I'd like to stick to official 3.0.1 release if possible.

Comment: Yes, I am the same bad guy unfortunately. What I said is applicable to 3.0.1 as well, although I will highly recommend upgrading to 3.1 when it comes out very soon, because I have fixed a number of issues in osgi-web-container in 3.1 release.